# Trigger a function when three consecutive wrong password tries

Tags: java, android, mobile

I am a beginner in android development.
The android Device have password to use. The password may numeric or some pattern.
I want to Trigger a function when anyone tries three consecutive wrong password inputs.
I am not making a password app. The password app will be an security app chosen by the device user.
When ever anyone try that security app password to assess the device then function will be Trigger.
My app trigger when other security app password is accessed 

Thanks in advance

Comment: show what you've tried so far...

Comment: Agree with @Sionnach733 ... Without trying anything do not post a question. If you have tried then state what you have tried and what did not work.

Answer (score 1):

Have a class variable called `passwordRetryCount = 0;`

Then everytime the user types a password, if it is wrong, say the following:

`passwordRetryCount++;`

`if (passwordRetryCount == 3) {
    //trigger function
}`